# How do I integrate Office Fluent UI React into a Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, office-ui-fabric, blazor-client-side, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm interested in [using the controls in OfficeUI /Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web) in a Blazor Webassembly project.

How can I add these items, ideally so that I don't have a dependency on a server runtime (and can use Azure Blobs) to host a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BlazorFluentUI library (https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI) provides a strong starting point.  It implements at least a large percentage of the core Fluent UI and is available in both WASM and Server-Side projects.